# MonoTouch.Dialog - last row visible?

Tags: c#, uitableview, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

How can I check if the MonoTouch.Dialog's last row (bottom `Element`) is visible?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have a reference to the `RootElement` and the *row*, i.e. the `Element`, you can do something like:

```
var tableview = root_element.TableView;
bool b1 = tableview.IndexPathsForVisibleRows.Contains (first_element.IndexPath);
bool b2 = tableview.IndexPathsForVisibleRows.Contains (last_element.IndexPath);
```

In this case `b1` would be `true` if the first row is visible while `b2` would be `false` if the last row is not visible.